# How do you evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$ ? I can't seem to deal well with $f_n(x)$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $$f_n:[0,\infty) \to R, f_n(x) = e^{-nx}\sin(nx), n \geq 0$$

How do you evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$$?

I am having troubles getting the limit. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Another possibility (other than the hint in the answer) is using the sandwich rule: $-e^{-nx}\leq f_n(x) \leq e^{-nx}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have $0< e^{-nx}\rightarrow 0$, hence $ e^{-nx}\sin(nx)\rightarrow 0$.
The "hence" can be obtained at least in two ways:

1. Given $\epsilon$ find $\delta$ for $ e^{-nx}$ and observe that the same applies to $ e^{-nx}\sin(nx)$.
2. "The Sandwich Rule": If $a_n\le b_n\le c_n$, and $a_n,c_n\rightarrow d$, then $b_n\rightarrow d$ (this is in many textbooks and fairly easy to prove). Set $a_n=-e^{-nx}$, $b_n:=f_n(x)$, $c_n=$find yourself.

Case $x=0$ is easy. Case $x<0$: show that for each $N$ there exists $n,m>N$ with $f_n(x)>1$ and $f_m(1)<0$ to prove that $f_n$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you. Once I though of x as a constant that is fixed before taking the limit, the things clarified. :D

Comment: But I guess you have a typo, when you said $a_n=-e^{-nx}$                                  Oh, wait. It was not a typo. I found $c_n=e^{-nx}$ and now it works

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Observe that $|\!\sin nx| \leq 1$, $e^{0}\sin 0 = 0$, and $e^{-nx} \to 0$ for any $x > 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Now squeeze.